# Rotation direction continuos check

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, angle, difference

I'm working on a moltitouch application in actionscript 3,  I'm also porting it in C#, Basically, im working on a Knob, that can be rotated with a finger, what i would like to achieve is that rotating CW or CCW i can have continuos direction, instead everytime angle is passing by 180 I got an inversion of direction, any hint ?

Which way can be detected a continuos rotation  direction ?

this is the code I'm uding to detect direction:

```
private function findDirection(currentAngle : Number, targetAngle : Number) : int
{
    currentAngle = refineAngle(currentAngle);
    targetAngle = refineAngle(targetAngle);

    if (targetAngle < 0)
    {
        targetAngle +=  (Math.PI * 2);
    }

    if (currentAngle < 0)
    {
        currentAngle +=  (Math.PI * 2);
    }

    if (targetAngle < currentAngle)
    {
        targetAngle +=  (Math.PI * 2);
    }

    if (targetAngle - currentAngle <= Math.PI)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}

private function refineAngle(angle : Number) : Number
{
    return angle * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

Comment: `currentAngel` and `targetAngle` are greater than or equal to 0 and smaller than 360?

Comment: these angles are between 0 and 360

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps. The variable `continuousAngle` will track the total knob turning performed, i.e. turning the knob twice counterclockwise will get you to `720`. Then turning it three times clockwise takes you back down to `-360`. Everything else should be easy to derive - limiting the minimum and maximum values, making the value wrap around, scale the value to for example `1` per turn or whatever else you want.

```
var lastAngle = 0;

var continuousAngle = 0;

function HandleDown(angle)
{
    lastAngle = angle;
}

function HandleMove(angle)
{
    // The orientation change in degrees of the knob since the last event with
    // a range of [-180;+180). A positive value indicates counterclockwise, a
    // negative value clockwise turning.
    var change = (360 + angle - lastAngle) % 360;

    if (change >= 180)
    {
        change -= 360;
    }

    // It may also be a good idea to not update continuousAngle if the absolute
    // value of change is larger than say 10°, 20° or 40° because such large
    // changes may indicate some kind of glitch like the user moving straight
    // across the knob. But I am not sure and 20 is just a random guess.
    if (Math.Abs(change) <= 20)
    {
        continuousAngle += change;
    }

    lastAngle = angle;
}
```

For floating point numbers the reminder can be calculated using [`Math.IEEEReminder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ieeeremainder.aspx) instead of the remainder operator `%`. The linked page also shows how to implement this function yourself if it is not available in your language.

Comment: thanks for your time, solution is kinda elegant, anyway result is the same, it results to change every 180, more in deep i need to have a constant direction increment, it means that rotating ccw i have a number always growing and viceversa rotating cw, any suggestion about it ?

Comment: Then I probably misunderstood what you parameters are. What data are you getting from the UI? The current angle of the mouse cursor or finger every time it changes and down and up events?

Comment: Maybe i was not so clear, I apologize for that, from Ui i get the angle from pointer (mouse or touch) around the center of knob, it means once i clicked i have a startangle and teh continuosly, by dragging, the currentAngle, those 2 angles are used to detect a continuos rotation: If i click and drag circularly the knob, after 360 degrees CCW i should obtain a value 0,1; doing it CCW value is 0, -1, hope i was clear and thank you for interest :)